# Min of a couple of values which must not be 0

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I need the minimum of `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`. But when one or more of them is 0 they fall out of the comparison. I could solve this with an `if`/`else` cascade but that is kind of ugly. Is there a cleaner way to solve this? `Math.min` alone doesn't work because it will result in a 0 when ever one of the variables is a 0.

Can I put them in an array and drop all the 0 in that array? Is there a `Math.min` for arrays?

```
bestPrice: Ember.computed('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', function() {
  var a = this.get('a');
  var b = this.get('b');
  var c = this.get('c');
  var d = this.get('d');

  return Math.min(a, b, c, d);
}),
```

Example:

- a = 0
- b = 10
- c = 20
- d = 30

bestPrice: 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
prices: Ember.computed.collect('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'),

bestPrice: Ember.computed('prices', function() {
  var nonzero = this.get('prices').filter(function (x) { return x > 0; });
  return Math.min.apply(null, nonzero);
}),
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to ignore 0, another way, different from filtering/reducing, would be to replace `0` values with `+Infinity`, so `Math.min` would not consider them as the smallest:

```
bestPrice: Ember.computed('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', function() {
    var a = this.get('a') || Infinity;
    var b = this.get('b') || Infinity;
    var c = this.get('c') || Infinity;
    var d = this.get('d') || Infinity;

    return Math.min(a, b, c, d);
 })
```

Pros:

- no if-else-s
- no unnecessary array instances and iteration over them

Cons:

- it's a bit of a hack
- works only with 0-s

Answer (score 0):

Why not put them in an array and loop through them? Each iteration of the loop checks if a value is not zero AND is less than the current minimum. Something like

```
var values = [a, b, c, d],
var min = -1;
for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
{
    if(values[i] == 0)
        continue;

    if(values[i] < min || min == -1) // Also check if min is not yet assigned a value
        min = values[i];
}

return min;
```

Btw, sorry if any of my syntax is wrong. My Javascript is a bit rusty now.